# Two handles to same variable in C

Tags: c

Is there any way I can create two variables that point to the same memory location, so that I can read same memory as int, float, char, any way I like?

I want something like this, only without pointer to f, so that I do not have to dereference every time I read/write to f.

```
char myArray[100];
float* f = (float *)&myArray[10];
```

I want to closest thing to C++'s reference in C.

I hope the question makes sense.

Edit: I read stream (4 Kb worth) of bytes from flash memory. This stream contains shorts, ints and floats. I know the locations of these ints and floats in the array. And I want to read/write the aforementioned ints and floats like they are ordinary variables.

Comment: Are you looking for the idea of a `union`? Also, `C++` has references. Anyways, keep in mind that this is dangerous; if you put a `float` in some region of memory, then reread and modify it as if it were an `int`, then read it as a `float` again, then I believe compiler is perfectly within its rights to completely ignore the changes you made.

Comment: *"I know the locations of these ints and floats in the array."* So why don't you declare a (packed?) `struct` that matches the data?

Comment: @WeatherVane, could I be able to read the raw bytes into the struct?

Comment: Can you give us an example of the layout of your stream?

Comment: @haxan7 my answer shows an example reading from binary file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This example reads the data into a predefined `struct`, packed (if necessary). Beware of endian-ness! And of data types: an `int` on your target might be `short` on you PC.

```
#include<stdio.h>

#pragma pack(push, 1)
struct mydata {
    int version;
    char title[16];
    float reading[8];
} mydata;

#pragma pack(pop)

int main(void)
{
    FILE *fp;
    struct mydata data = {0};
    fp = fopen("mydata.bin", "rb");

    if (1 != fread(&data, sizeof(data), 1, fp))
        { // error
        }

    printf("Version = %d\n", data.version);

    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: typo: fread(&data, sizeof(data), 1, fp) should be fread(&data, 1, sizeof(data), fp)

Comment: @haxan7 nope. I am checking that 1 record of that size is read. It *could*  be the other way round, but you would then have to check `if (sizeof(data) != fread(&data, 1, sizeof(data), fp))`. Please look up `fread` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kt0etdcs.aspx

Comment: this is where I go for documentation http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fread/

Comment: you have been most helpful, do I need to be worried about this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3638317/why-does-a-struct-consisting-of-a-char-short-and-char-in-that-order-when-co ?

Comment: Yes, that and endian-ness as I commented.

Answer (score 1):

This is why *unions* exist.

```
union u {
  char c[4];
  float f;
  int i; // assuming sizeof(int) = 4 for this example
};

union u cf;
cf.f = 1.;
int i = cf.i;
```

Beware that the last line is actually incorrect per the C standard, because of strict aliasing. See for example [What is the strict aliasing rule?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule) You should always access the binary representation through a `char` l-value.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question, I have updated my question for clarification.

Comment: I'm still not sure I understand what you mean. It seems you want to read through the stream using a pointer that you increment? If so, you could declare a pointer to `union u`. However, this will require some care before performing the incrementation. I think the suggestion of @Weather Vane is actually simpler.